# Getting HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type with Jersey

Tags: java, http, jersey-2.0, http-status-code-415

Below is my POJO class

```
public class Credentials {
private int cred_id;
private String cred_user_name;
private String cred_password;
private String cred_token;

public Credentials(int cred_id, String cred_user_name,
        String cred_password, String cred_token) {
    this.cred_id = cred_id;
    this.cred_user_name = cred_user_name;
    this.cred_password = cred_password;
    this.cred_token = cred_token;
}

public int getCred_id() {
    return cred_id;
}

public void setCred_id(int cred_id) {
    this.cred_id = cred_id;
}

public String getCred_user_name() {
    return cred_user_name;
}

public void setCred_user_name(String cred_user_name) {
    this.cred_user_name = cred_user_name;
}

public String getCred_password() {
    return cred_password;
}

public void setCred_password(String cred_password) {
    this.cred_password = cred_password;
}

public String getCred_token() {
    return cred_token;
}

public void setCred_token(String cred_token) {
    this.cred_token = cred_token;
}
```

}

Below is my resource class

```
public class ValidateUser {
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String validateUser(Credentials credentials) {
    System.out.println("Going to validate the user" + credentials);
    String username = credentials.getCred_user_name();
    String password = credentials.getCred_password();
    CredentialsAccessor ca = new CredentialsAccessor();
    long count = 0;
    count = ca.authenticateUser(username, password);
    if (count > 0) {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jObject.put("valid", "true");
            return jObject.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "{'valid':'error'}";
        }
    } else {
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jObject.put("valid", "false");
            return jObject.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "{'valid':'error'}";
        }
    }
}
```

}

[Please see the maven dependencies here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbiOs.jpg)

I ensured that in the RESTClient i give the content type as Content-Type:application/json

[Please see the RESTClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Sj1l.jpg)

Below is my web.xml

But even then i get the error '**Getting HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media**'

Can you image, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I See you have MOXy. But MOXy only knows how to handle classes annotated with `@XmlRootElement`. That's the reason for the 415: Jersey can't find a `MessageBodyReader` to handle the type.

After you add the `@XmlRootElement` on top of the `Credentials` class, you're going to get another error because MOXy will not be able to actually deserialize the JSON to your `Credentials`. The reason is that there's no default (no-arg) constructor. So add that, and I'm thinking you should be good.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked exactly like you have described.